# Explicit formula for $J[X,Y](f)$?

Tags: complex-geometry, lie-derivative, almost-complex

Let $(M,J)$ be a complex manifold. I'm trying to find an explicit formula for $(J[X,Y])(f)$, like how for the simple commutator we have (by definition even)
$$ [X,Y](f) = X(Y(f)) - Y(X(f)) $$
I'm trying to use the vanishing of the Nijehnuis tensor, which gives:
$$ [X,Y] = [JX, JY] - J[JX,Y] - J[X,JY] $$
and so
$$ J[X,Y] = J[JX, JY] + [JX, Y] + [X,JY] $$
But this doesn't seem to lead anywhere since I still have the $J[JX,JY]$ term.

Comment: Such formula would involve $J, X$ and $Y$, and I wonder if one can find a simpler formula than $J[X, Y]$...